# Is static variable shared between class instances

Tags: c#, class, static

I have the class below. _commandLine variable is declared as static. Does this variable will be shared between WkHtml class instances?

p.s. It would be cool to have Tool which would show such information in VS. For example developer select variable and get information about variable, is variable shared between classes, is it thread safe and etc.

```
public class WkHtml
{
    private static string _commandLine;

    public void AddCommandLine(object value)
    {
        AddCommandLine("{0}", value);
    }

    public void AddCmdWithCond(string value, bool condition, object compareValue)
    {
        AddCmdWithCond(value, condition, compareValue, "");
    }

    public void AddCmdWithCond(string value, bool condition, object compareValue, string defaultValue)
    {
        if (compareValue != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(compareValue.ToString()) && Helpers.GetBool(compareValue) == condition)
            AddCommandLine("{0}", value);
        else
            if (defaultValue != null)
                AddCommandLine("{0}", defaultValue);
    }

    public void AddCommandLine(object parameter, object value, object defaultValue)
    {
        if (value == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString()))
        {
            value = defaultValue;
        }
        AddCommandLine(parameter, value);
    }

    public void AddCommandLine(object parameter, object value)
    {
        if (value == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString())) return;
        _commandLine = _commandLine + string.Format(parameter.ToString(), value) + " ";
    }

    public string GetCommandLine
    {
        get { return _commandLine; }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`static` variables are shared between all class instances.

I don't see any reason to why you should declare it as static?

Comment: Strong +1 on the last point; `static` here looks entirely incorrect

Answer (score 5):

> Does this variable will be shared between WkHtml class instances?

yes it does - and equally, it applies to none, but rather: the type itself. You can use a static variable without any instances of the type.

> and get information about variable, is variable shared between classes

you already do - the `S` symbol in intellisense, and the `static` modifier.

> is it thread safe

that is more complicated, and cannot be evaluated by such - it is impossible to comment on thread-safety without a deep understanding of the code and how it is used.

Comment: A string in C# is threadsafe because it's immutable. Why shouldn't it be threadsafe? (I'll add that he is using in a non-threadsafe way, because he rereads the value multiple times in the same function, thinking the value won't change between reads)

Comment: @xanatos the *string* is not the variable - it is the object. Yes, a string **object** is thread-safe (barring nasty hacks), but the string *variable* is not. `_commandLine = _commandLine + string....` is a prime example; that ignores competing changes and can result in lost data.

Comment: I think that then the reply should have been "in your code no", because he made that particular error in `_commandLine = _commandLine + string.Format(parameter.ToString(), value) + " ";`

Comment: @xanatos it is meaningless to ponder the thread-safety of a variable *except* by looking at how it is used in the code.

Answer (score 2):

yes it is a class variable,all instances of the class will have see the same value of the property.if one instance changes it ,it will reflect for all the instances.

Answer (score 1):

`static` variables are indeed "shared" between class instances, though it is instance independent.   A `static` variable is part of the class, but not instances of that class.